# Read string with spaces in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

In this C++ code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string S;
    getline(cin,S);
    cout<<S;

    return 0;
}
```

It prints the string with spaces, eg:

Input:

```
abc def
```

Output:

```
abc def
```

However, in this code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    string S;
    getline(cin,S);
    cout<<S;

    return 0;
}
```

It does not print any output, eg:

Input:

```
1
abc def
```

Output:

How is that even possible? Please help. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You read a number and then a line. Think carefully about what is going on, a newline is not part of a number. So if the input is 123 newline, you read the number 123 and then getline reads the newline. Whatever is on the next line hasn't been read at all.

Comment: I have edited the question, there were some formatting issues.
Please look at it now.

Comment: @Saarthak OK, but the answer is the same.

Comment: Your mistake is thinking that each read starts from the next line. That is not true.

Comment: Using cin.ignore() after the number provides the desired solution :)

Comment: OK, now try your solution on 123 space newline. ignore() only ignores a single character. The complete solution is in the linked answer.